# What are possible 3rd Party Payment Systems to integrate in iPhone Apps?

Tags: iphone

Apple states in its [App Store Review Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) "Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected". So is it then legal to implement other payment services than Apple's In-App-Purchase to buy physical goods? I could imagine services like PayPal, Amazon or Google Checkout but don't have any experience with those and if they are usable within iPhone Apps.

Comment: This is probably a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use outside services.

**[PayPal's Express Checkout for Mobile Devices](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices)** definitely works this way.

That I've been able to determine, neither of **[Amazon's mobile payment systems](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business/mobile/overview)** allows for true in-app integration; instead you'd have to use a UIWebView and have the user checkout through the web while inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine if you use a UIWebView. Apple states that charity apps must use Safari Mobile, so I assume that this is similar. Just display a UIWebView in place and have it load your web form.

Comment: pardon me but where can i find such documentations, can u plz provide me with links

Comment: @sole007 [here ya go](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nordic company named, "DIBS A/S" which have a mobile paymentwindow.
In this case you both need an agreement with DIBS and a acquirer agreement.

So depending on how many transactions you are exepting to have, maybe paypal is cheaper for a small amount of transactions.

Their service can properly be used in a UIWebView. :)

Here is a link: [www.dibs.com](http://www.dibs.com)