# how we integrate payment gateways in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, payment-gateway

How to implement payment gateways in iPhone app?

Also is there any problem of app rejecting by using a third-party payment gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not attempt to create a payment gateway by your self unless you are thoroughly conversant with programming, security and you completely understand everything involved. There are too much factors and security issues involved. Use something like PayPal or read up on [In-App Purchase Programming Guide[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) in Apple Dev guide.

Comment: I'm not trying to create my own payment gateway.I need to use some third party payment gateways.Is paypal or other gateways like eWAY,authorize.net accepted by Apple?Thanks for replying

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992717/what-are-possible-3rd-party-payment-systems-to-integrate-in-iphone-apps

Comment: does users required the paypal account for making their payments

Answer (score 0):

Use the paypal mobile sdk..For integrating the payment gateway in your application..You can download the sample project from  github by clicking download zip.
If you want to use digital goods payment service then best way to use inapppurchase (tutorial is given in reywenderlich) 
If u want to use real goods payment they u can use paypal or other related payment gateway..

You can go...developer.paypal.com for more info regarding this..

Comment: does users required the paypal account for making their payments